# Cycle through tabular data on single screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to determine a good way to accomplish the following. I want to build a small application to display tabular data similar to a airport arrival/departure board.

I want to constrain the tabular data to a single screen and periodically cycle through the data since there could potentially be more data than can fit on a single screen.

I would like each "page" of data to be displayed for a brief period without refreshing the entire page. For example if there are 60 records the application would show the first 25 rows on a single screen for a few seconds, switch to the next 25, then show the last 10, and finally return to the first 25, and on and on.

I am using MVC 5 and I plan to use SignalR to update the underlying data periodically, but am not sure the best way to go to cycle through the display.

Comment: You could just use a [javascript timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) to periodically call a server method that passes the page number and returns a partial view of the results and update the DOM (SignalR would not be necessary), or you could render all the elements with only the first 25 visible and use the time to show/hide the others as required (SignalR would be necessary to update any new items)

Comment: Have you found W3.CSS Slideshow yet? http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp It looks like a really easy way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I ended up configuring a DataTables table and using the paging API to do what I needed https://datatables.net/reference/api/page(). The table works very nice and has lots of other options I can leverage.